# Получить геолокацию через Telegram бота с помощью inline

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telethon

Если в Телеграме использовать бота через Inline, то бот может запросить местоположение пользователя, если это включено в настройках бота. За получение геолокации отвечает класс [telethon.events.inlinequery.InlineQuery](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/events.html#telethon.events.inlinequery.InlineQuery).

Вот псевдокод, через который я *пытался* получить геолокацию, чтобы в будущем использовать широту и долготу:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events

@client.on(events.InlineQuery)
async def handler(event):
    location = event.geo
    builder = event.builder

    await event.answer([
        builder.article("Координаты", text="Долгота: " + location.long + " Широта: " + location.lat),
    ])
```

Но у меня ничего не выходит. Постоянно выдает `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lat'`.

Буду признателен если поможете в получении и **использовании** этих данных.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это был баг, который каждый раз возвращал None. Было исправлено в следующей версии Telethon.